# How can I make a span stretch the available space between to other spans?

Tags: css, width, html

I want to create an element that consists of three spans within a div. The three spans shall use the whole width provided by the div. The left and right span have a fixed width and the centre one should use the whole available space between them. I've been trying many different things (float, overflow, etc.) but I haven't found an answer yet and I'm running out of ideas...

The code is rather simple:

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="rowLeft">LEFT</span>
  <span class="rowCentre">CENTER</span>
  <span class="rowRight">RIGHT</span>
</div>
```

using the following CSS:

```
.row {
  display: block;
  height: 62px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.rowLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.rowCentre {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.rowRight {
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

I've created a jsFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezAdf/

**Question**: Starting from here, how can I make the centre span stretch the available space between left and right span?

Comment: Search for fluid layout with fixed sidebars

Comment: Thanks, that is at least a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda like @j08691's solution, with some changes. (Works in 4 browsers though.)
I removed the floats, added `display: table-cell` to **span** and `display: table` plus `width: 100%` to **.row**

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WmpZG/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display:table-cell` CSS property on each span, and then set the width on the center span to 100%.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ezAdf/2/)**

```
.row {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.rowLeft {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:table-cell;
}
.rowCentre {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;

}
.rowRight {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution breaks the defintion of the cell width. Try to set e.g. the width of .rowRight to 100px and you'll see that the width does not change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the your fiddle clearly shows that the _width_ of the cells is still not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following changes to your CSS file:

```
.row {
  display: block;
  height: 62px;
  border: 1px dotted black;   
  position: relative;
}

.rowLeft {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  float: left;
}

.rowCentre{
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  right: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;  
  float: left;
}

.rowRight{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;  
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help me because of the absolute position of the centre span. I want to create these elements dynamically, so the positions are not known upfront.